# Convert a Panel to DataFrame with multilevel columns of (minor, item)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas panel of:

```
Items axis: X1 to X3
Major_axis axis: (1973-09-30 00:00:00, 1989-03-31 00:00:00) to (2015-07-31 00:00:00, 2015-08-21 00:00:00)
Minor_axis axis: A to C
```

and I would like to convert it to a dataframe with a multilevel column of (Item, Minor), the multilevel columns would look as follows:

```
mi_tuples = [ ('A','X1'), ('A','X2'), ('A','X3'), ('B','X1'), ('B','X2'), ('B','X3'), ('C','X1'), ('C','X2'), ('C','X3') ]
mi_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(mi_tuples, names = ['minor', 'items'])
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think a combination of `to_frame`, `unstack`, and `swaplevel` can get you there.  See below with some example data.

```
In [134]: pnl = pd.io.data.DataReader(['GOOG', 'AAPL'], 'yahoo')

In [135]: pnl
Out[135]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 1421 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Open to Adj Close
Major_axis axis: 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2015-08-25 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: AAPL to GOOG

In [136]: df = pnl.to_frame().unstack(level=1)

In [137]: df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)

In [138]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1421 entries, 2010-01-04 to 2015-08-25
Data columns (total 12 columns):
(AAPL, Open)         1421 non-null float64
(GOOG, Open)         357 non-null float64
(AAPL, High)         1421 non-null float64
(GOOG, High)         357 non-null float64
(AAPL, Low)          1421 non-null float64
(GOOG, Low)          357 non-null float64
(AAPL, Close)        1421 non-null float64
(GOOG, Close)        357 non-null float64
(AAPL, Volume)       1421 non-null float64
(GOOG, Volume)       357 non-null float64
(AAPL, Adj Close)    1421 non-null float64
(GOOG, Adj Close)    357 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(12)
memory usage: 144.3 KB
```